# How to use a path helper with jquery click event?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a div within an erb template that when clicked I want to trigger the show action of a controller.

```
<div class = "box"> 
  Content within the box
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').click(function(){
      $.get(<%=hack_path(h) %>)
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm receiving the error 'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)'.  I'm wondering whether I on the right track/pattern to achieve the desired result or should I be using some other technique?

Here is the actual template:

```
<h1>Hacks</h1>

<% @hack.each do |h| %> 
  <div class = "box">
    <table>
    <h3><%= h.hack_name %></b></h3>
    <%= h.id %>
    <span id = "showhack"> <%= link_to 'Show', hack_path(h) %></span>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_hack_path(h) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', hack_path(h), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <%= link_to "Get Data", :controller => :admins, :action => :checkSerials, :method => :get %>

  <% h.serials.each do |s| %>  
    <tr>
      <th>Series Title</th>
      <th>Series Name</th>
      <th>Series Id</th>
      <% s.observations.sort{|a,b| a.id <=> b.id}.last(5).each do |o| %>
        <th><%= o.date %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to s.title, [h, s] %></td>
      <td><%= s.series_name %></td>
      <td><%= s.id %></td>
    <% s.observations.sort{|a,b| a.id <=> b.id}.last(5).each do |o| %>
    <% if s.units_short == 'Mil. of $' %>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(convertMtoBHack(o.value), :precision => 0) %></td>
    <% else %>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(o.value, :precision => 0) %></td>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= s.frequency_short %></td>
    <td><%= s.units_short %></td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
</table>
</div>
```

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('.box').click(function(){
   $.get(<%= hack_path(@hack).to_json %>)
   });
  });
 </script>

<div><%= link_to 'New Hack', new_hack_path %></div>
```

Comment: Jeez, you broke the code highlighter, well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the string. Otherwise it will be rendered as `$.get(/what/ever/path)` which of course is wrong.

I recommend to use `to_json()`, it protects you against other nasties as well:

```
$.get(<%= hack_path(h).to_json %>) 
# renders to $.get("/what/ever/path")
```

But usually you have multiple places where the same handler is being used and you will end up adding the URLS to the markup using data tags and reading them using `$.data()`.

```
<div data-url=<%= hack_path(h).to_json %>>
```

and within the javascript part:

```
var url = $(target).data("url");
```

For example if you want to make the title of the 'hack' clickable:

```
<td class="hacktitle" data-url=<%= hack_url(h).to_json %>><%= link_to s.title, [h, s] %></td>

/* somewhere else in javascript */

$("table.hacks").on("click", "td.hacktitle", function(event) {
    var targetTd = $(event.target);
    var url = targetTd.data("url");
    $.get(url);
```

All this is even more convenient when you use HAML (which I would recommend anyway)

```
%div{:data => {:url => hack_path()}}
  some content
```

Comment: There's probably user error here but when I tried using $.get(<%= hack_path(h).to_json %>), I received the same 'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)'.  I know the hack_path(h) "works" because I have it as part of a link_to on the page.  When I tried changing the <div class="box" data-url=<%= hack_path(h).to_json %>> and then var url = $(target).data("url"); with $.get(url); I received 'Uncaught Reference Error' in the browser console.

Comment: Are you sure `h`is correct? There is also a function called `h()` which takes one argument. If you didn't specify your local variable correctly you might call `h()` instead of using the variable.

Comment: and the example with the `$(target)!  was just.. well, an example. You have to adapt it to your case.

Comment: I added my erb file to my question.  The h was not correct because I was doing a do loop to populate all of the Hacks in the Hack model.  Which presents me with the issue of passing the correct "box" that was 'clicked'.  So maybe I should "store" the id for the record in the data tag and then grab it and build it into the path passed to  $.get?

Comment: ha :) you correctly analyzed your problem. It was a bit confusing because h() is a function and therefore Ruby didn't complain about an undefined local variable. I'll extend my answer a bit.

Comment: First thank you for your genius and your patience. I know your trying to teach me to fish instead of laying it out but I've changed my "box" div to <div class = "box" data-url= <%= hack_path(h).to_json %>>.  I've changed the jquery code to: $('div').on("click", "div.box", (function(target){
      var url = $(target).data("url");
      console.log(url);
    }));
  });  I'm getting undefined for my url variable and cannot figure out why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25791/discussion-between-reto-and-johngalt)